# Cocos2d-x CCMenuItemToggle response on touchend instead of touchbegan

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

My toggle menu item responds on touch as soon as i touch it. I want it to respond on touch end that is when i take my finger up. Any Ideas????
Here is my code

```
CCMenuItemSprite* p1 = CCMenuItemSprite::create(CMBaseSprite::initWithBaseSprite("ss_On"), CMBaseSprite::initWithBaseSprite("ss_off"));
CCMenuItemSprite* p2 = CCMenuItemSprite::create(CMBaseSprite::initWithBaseSprite("ss_off"), CMBaseSprite::initWithBaseSprite("ss_On"));
CCMenuItemToggle* pSoundToggle = CCMenuItemToggle::createWithTarget(this, menu_selector(SettingsLayer::turnOnOffMusic), p1, p2, NULL);
pSoundToggle->setPosition(ccp(settingsLayerSprite->getContentSize().width * 0.5, settingsLayerSprite->getContentSize().height* 0.62));
pSoundsMenu->addChild(pSoundToggle);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in IOS as you asked for like activate on touch end only. Here is e.g.

```
    CCMenuItem *soundOnItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"soundOn.png"
                                                     selectedImage:@"soundOn.png"];

    CCMenuItem *soundOffItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"soundOff.png"
                                                      selectedImage:@"soundOff.png"];

CCMenuItemToggle *soundToggleItem;
 if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"sound"])
        soundToggleItem = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self    
                                                  selector:@selector(sound)    
                                                  items:soundOnItem,
                                                  soundOffItem, nil];
    else
        soundToggleItem = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self
                                                  selector:@selector(sound) 
                                                  items:soundOffItem, 
                                                  soundOnItem, nil];
```